# How to Avoid the Black/Splash screen on Android using Flash CS6

Tags: android, actionscript-3, splash-screen, flash-cs6

I am using Flash CS6 to develop and IOS and Android application. from what i have understood, that iPhone has the feature of Splash screen but android doesn't support it.

i can configure successfully the splash screen on iPhone by adding Default.bng but that doesn't work for me on Android

i tried to find the solutions here, or in Google about how to configure it, but as well i couldn't find the right solution.

I dont know if Splash screen is going to solve my issue, my exact problem is there is about 1 minute of black screen appears when i open the application on My phone. this black screen doesn't look on Flash simulator. its only appears on my android phone.

Comment: I think splash screen will work

Comment: android don't have a splashScreen concept. the splash screen we see in android app is an activity that is shown for some seconds. so if its takes 1 min to load your application it wont be reduced by splash screen. the splash will be shown after the 1 min loading

Answer (score 0):

create a activity or fragment i here used activity

```
    setContentView(your layout);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            //call your main activity and finish this activity
        }
    }, time duration for splashscreen in milliseconds);
```

Comment: I am talking about Flash CS6 or by using Action Script not by Java android. i know i can do it in java android, but i am using CS6 cross platform.